# How to rename a mail-enabled security group?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2003, best-practices

I work in an organization that is prone to frequently renaming teams.

What is the best way to manage name changes to mail-enabled security groups?  So far, I have just been using the ADUC GUI on our Exchange Server.  I rename the group name then open properties and fix the various Exchange related attributes.

Should I be scripting this for efficiency and accuracy?  Should I be concerned about deleting old smtp addresses?  Should I be taking steps to prevent client cached GAL names and addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 2003, I don't believe the scripting interfaces are all that convenient to use. They are for 2007 and 2010, but not 03. The methods you're using match what we were doing when we did renames. We tried to prevent them where possible, but sometimes... you just have to do it.

- Rename the various AD names in ADUC
- Rename the various Exchange names in ADUC+plugins
- Preserve the old SMTP addresses for backwards compatibility (this can cause problems later on down the road from name-collisions, but at least mail doesn't bounce)
- Preserve the old X500 addresses for backwards compatibility

The x500 addresses are more important that people realize since that's how Exchange stores addresses internally.

Comment: Thanks, we have x.400 addresses (I gather as legacy from Exchange 5.5?) and I don't see new ones created when I change any of the Exchange attributes.